# Many-to-many relationships issue in CakePHP model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I am having issues getting all the data from a relationship.  Here are my tables:

```
**Regions**    
id(pk)
regions_name

**Areas**    
id(pk)
areas_name
regions_id (fk)

**carDealer**    
id(pk)
dealer_name
areas_id(fk)
```

I would think that with this design, I should be able to query Regions like this:

```
    $this->Region->recursive = 5;
    $getRegions = $this->Region->find('all');
```

And get an array of all Regions, which would have a sub array of Areas, which would have a sub array of carDealers.

My code, only brings back the Regions and Areas array but not carDealers.  Here is some relevant code to my models:

Regions Table

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');    
class Region extends AppModel {    
    public $validate = array(    
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(    
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Areas' => array(
            'className' => 'Areas',
            'foreignKey' => 'regions_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),   
    );
}
```

Areas Table:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Area extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
    );    
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Regions' => array(
            'className' => 'Regions',
            'foreignKey' => 'regions_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'carDealer' => array(
            'className' => 'carDealer',
            'foreignKey' => 'areas_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
}
```

Car Dealer Table:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class carDealer extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Areas' => array(
            'className' => 'Areas',
            'foreignKey' => 'areas_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
    );
}
```

Am I missing something in my models relationships?

thanks
jason

Comment: Please http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive   For recursive $this->Region->recursive = 5; only -1, 0, 1, 2 are there.

Comment: You need to check cake naming conventions, you are saying `public $belongsTo = array('Areas' => array('className' => 'Areas',` when clearly your className is `Region`, and a lot other tiny important details like that.http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Comment: Last comment fail... "when clearly your className is <strike>Region</strike> `Area`" (but it happens with `Region` too)

Comment: Thanks Nunser, that was the issue.  I thought the array was suppose to point to the actual table name (which is plural in my schema).  I switched it to the actual class name and that worked.  If you post this as a response I will give you the points for it.

Comment: chetan clearly put effort on his answer and it addresses every issue with your code. Accept it. Maybe next time I'll add a full answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo or hasOne relationships are recognized by default as the (singular) name of the related table followed by _id.

Go through http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

So your foreign key shoud be area_id , region_id

Need to change recursive level

```
 $this->Region->recursive = 1;
 $getRegions = $this->Region->find('all');
```

Need to modify className of Model relationship

It should be 'Area', 'Region','CarDealer'.

Need to remove unnecessary variable or array options

Region Model

```
<?php
 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');    
class Region extends AppModel {    
   public $hasMany = array(
    'Area' => array(
        'className' => 'Area',
        'foreignKey' => 'region_id'
       ),   
);
}
```

Area Model:

```
<?php
  App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
 class Area extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Region' => array(
        'className' => 'Region',
        'foreignKey' => 'region_id'
    ),
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'CarDealer' => array(
        'className' => 'CarDealer',
        'foreignKey' => 'area_id'
    ),
);
 }
```

CarDealer Model:

```
<?php
 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class CarDealer extends AppModel {
   public $belongsTo = array(
    'Area' => array(
        'className' => 'Area',
        'foreignKey' => 'area_id'
       ),
);
  }
```